# Adding lookups to given view

Tags: yii

I'm just getting into Yii. I have a simple relational db. I have a "client" table related to "orders" table (client:id to orders:client_id). If I build my CRUD for orders i naturally see client_id, however I'd rather add a lookup for client name somehow

I have found how to do this on new and update _forms by adding a dropDownList. The list based views seem a little more complex. I can see that actionIndex() in the controller is gathering data and passing it to index.php, finally through to _view, but I can't find any help on where and how I should break into this with my lookup returning the client name

I'd appreciate any help
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the Yii documentation about relations.  You will need to create a relation in your orders table, lets call it `client`,  Then in your list view where it generates `client_id` you can put `client.name` instead.  Now you will need to make sure that you have the appropriate label because in the generated model it will only have a label for `client_id`, and you need a label for `client.name`.  Yii will guess, or you can add it, or you can modify the label for client_id, and instead of using `client.name` in the view you can use

```
array(
   'name'=>'client_id',
   'value'=>$model->client->name,
)
```

I tend to gravitate towards more explicit definitions rather than shortcuts, but to each his own.